# Using define-word

Tags: key-bindings

I want to use dictionary on emacs and found [define-word](https://github.com/abo-abo/define-word). I downloaded it and wrote the following setting in `init.el`. But, I can't use this and any word return `0 definitions found`. Are other settings required? How do I fix it?

```el
(use-package define-word
  :config
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'define-word-at-point)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c D") 'define-word))
```

Comment: I get "Forbidden" when I try `(url-retrieve-synchronously url t t)` with the default `wordnik` URL. I tried the https variant too: no luck. Try one of the other services. Open an issue at the Github site and describe your findings.

Comment: By 'try one of the other services', I mean `M-x customize-variable RET define-word-default-service RET` and choose a different one: `webster` seems to work.

Comment: Changing ```define-word-default-service``` works. Thanks.